# Dynamically filter Haystack SearchQuerySet based on the user

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I need to filter Haystack's SearchQuerySet based on the current user. I know I can get the current user via `request.user` in other views, so I imagine I need to override Haystack's default SearchView, but I'm not sure how. Below is a sample of my urls.py and views.py.

```
urls.py:

urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.search.views',
    url(r'^mymodel/$', search_view_factory(
        view_class=MySearchView,
        template='mymodel_search.html',
        form_class=MyModelSearchForm,
        searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel),
    ), name='mymodel_search'),
    ...

views.py:

class MySearchView(SearchView):
    def build_form(self, form_kwargs=None):
        prop = UserProfile.objects.get(user = self.request.user).property
        self.searchqueryset = self.searchqueryset.filter(property = prop)

        return super(MySearchView, self).build_form(form_kwargs)
```

This doesn't seem to be working, though. Results are limited to MyModel (as filtered in urls.py), but the filtering in MySearchView doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a different way or place I should be doing this?

Comment: What are the available fields available in your index? and what search backend are you using

Comment: My backend is Solr 4.5.1. I have a couple fields in the text (document) field and several others for filtering through a form. The "property" field that I'm trying to filter in my example is also in the search index.

Comment: I realized I made a silly mistake, detailed below. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake. In my custom MyModelSearchForm's `search()` method, I was resetting the search query set to `SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel)`, so it replaced all previous filtering. The method I was attempting with `MySearchView` works.